# Alternating Ovulation

Tags: human-biology, physiology, reproduction, ovulation

I have often heard that right and left ovaries alternate in releasing ovum.

Is it always true? What controls this rhythm? Is it simply because the other ovary is unresponsive to LH or FSH? If so, why?

Comment: I am not sure if this alternation occurs. Can you post the reference ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nope, not true](http://humrep.oxfordjournals.org/content/15/4/752.full).  It's a pretty common myth; that paper cites a  reference from 1932 in primates claiming to show that the ovaries alternate.  A few papers before this, in particular [this one from 1991](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1988887?dopt=Abstract) showed that ovulation was *not* alternating, but this was the first to do so in actually fertile woman.  In particular,

> Alternate ovulation occurred in 61 of the 119 succeeding ovulations (51.3%, not significant) which means that there was no consistent tendency to alternation.

Alternation only occurred half the time.  Neither did they find a difference between side preference; right-side ovulation occurred in just over 50% of the cases, not significantly different.

FSH, follicle-stimulating hormone, and LH, luteinizing hormone, stimulate each ovary equally, but one ovary will get slightly ahead.  Ovulation (and indeed pregnancy at times) is a positive-feedback loop, meaning the response will be exponential; if one ovary is even just slightly ahead it will rapidly dominate the other.  The less-developed one quickly senses the other is ahead of the game and ceases to respond.

Comment: Can you provide details of the *positive feedback loop* and the *sensing the "lost race" by the less developed ovary* as mentioned in your answer?